# argc never has a value above 2

Tags: c++, argc

if i compile this code under Visual Studio 2013

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
std::cout << "arg count: "<< argc << "/n";
}
```

and then run it with no additional arguments (i.e. >program.exe), it outputs

```
arg count: 1
```

with 1 argument (>program.exe arg1) it outputs

```
arg count: 2
```

BUT this is where it gets weird. if i input (>program.exe arg1 arg2) it outputs

```
arg count: 2
```

"arg count" should be 3, shouldn't it?

with (>program.exe arg1 arg2 arg3) it outputs

```
arg count: 2
```

it should be 4 in this case...

printing argv[3] works fine for some reason.

why is this happening?

Comment: And what happens when you get rid of the attempt to print `argv[3]`? That introduces undefined behaviour to your program.

Comment: Can you show how you are supplying these arguments?  Specifically, how you are calling the program?

Comment: The last pointer from `argv` is usually initialized to `NULL`, that it's possible to iterate over the arguments without indexing.

Comment: Note that the standard C/C++ type to use here is 'char' not 'CHAR'.

Comment: What is `CHAR`? Please provide an SSCCE.

Comment: I pasted that code into VS 2013 and it doesn't build. Including iostream helps but CHAR isn't a thing. So show all your code. (Note: it should be \n) and when I changed CHAR to char it works fine and gets the correct # of arguments every time. VS 2013.

Comment: Have you tried printing `argv[1]` ? I wonder if for some reason all arguments are not stashed into a single one.

Comment: @tomatopipps This code should definitively work. Either you're messing up the arguments yourself or your build is broken. Have you tried restarting your computer? ;-)

Comment: Oh, a wild guess: Does your program name contain a `"`?

Answer (score 2):

Section `3.6.1` of the C++ standard defines how `main` and its arguments work:

> In the latter form, for purposes of exposition, the first function parameter is
>   called *argc* and the second function parameter is called *argv*, where *argc* shall be the number of arguments
>   passed to the program from the environment in which the program is run. If *argc* is nonzero these arguments
>   shall be supplied in *argv[0]* through *argv[argc-1]* as pointers to the initial characters of null-terminated
>   multibyte strings (ntmbs s) (17.5.2.1.4.2) and *argv[0]* shall be the pointer to the initial character of a
>   ntmbs that represents the name used to invoke the program or "". The value of *argc* shall be non-negative.
>   **The value of argv[argc] shall be 0**. [ Note: It is recommended that any further (optional) parameters be
>   added after argv. —end note ]

That means with a standard-conforming compiler, you should be able to access `argv[argc]`.
Accessing `argv[n]` with n > `argc` is undefined though. It may crash, but doesn't have to.

What you're experiencing is weird, as apparently the arguments are processed as a single argument. If you provide the arguments exactly as stated, this should not happen.

You should fix the signature of `main`. The standard guarantees at least these two signatures, anything else is implementation-defined:

> — a function of () returning int and
>
> — a function of (int, pointer to pointer to char) returning int

As you want to access arguments, the appropriate signature is `int main(int argc, char** argv)`.

Comment: my problem is that argc isn't reflecting the value of the amount of arguments, i edited the question to be more concise.

Comment: In the context of function arguments, `char **argv` is equivalent to `char *argv[]`.

Comment: @AmbrozBizjak The old version of the question had `CHAR` as type, what is clearly wrong (unless it's a typedef of `char`). I'm reffering to that.

Comment: “ This is most probably a compiler bug.” – In fact, it’s most probably *not* a compiler bug but rather an error in usage. A compiler bug for such a basic feature can be excluded with near certainty. Every other explanation, including that the OP is simply mistaken, is more likely.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I was suspecting an ancient non-conforming compiler until I read about VS2013. You're right, that's probably not true => removed.

Answer (score 1):

ok, as it turns out, the problem was in some code i didn't include here. my code was:

```
if (argc = 2) { do some stuff }
```

it should have been

```
if (argc == 2) { do some stuff }
```

i feel really stupid :\

Comment: Enable warnings and such a mistake doesn't happen again. I don't know the flag for VS2013 though.

Comment: warning level 4. Right click the project in Solution Explorer, choose Properties, in the tree on the left click C/C++, find Warning Level and drop it down to change to Level4. Don't choose all, most libraries can't go clean on the All level.

Comment: @Kate Does VC++ have a special compiler flag to include libraries’ include files and ignore their warnings? GCC/clang have `-isystem` for that. This way I can compile my own code with the highest warning level. Without it I’d go crazy.

Comment: I wish, but I don't think so @KonradRudolph

Answer (score 0):

I can guess that either you enter as

(>program.exe "arg1 arg2"

or

```
(>program.exe arg1,arg2
```